# Horizontally scroll div elements on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with items that has a horizontal scroll. That works fine. What I want to add, is the ability to click a button that will scroll the corresponding element into view.

My thinking is, for now, the .scrollNav-item, once clicked will cause the corresponding item to scroll into view, probably next to the left edge of .horizontalScroll.

I have no JS at this point, and I'm writing and re-writing as I try different thing.

This is my HTML:

```css
.horizontalScroll {
  display : flex;
  overflow-x : scroll;
  overflow-y : hidden;

  padding : 0 0 25px 0;

  flex-flow : row nowrap;

  &-item {
    width : 300px;
    margin-right : 15px;
    margin-left : 0;
  }


  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width : 80%;
    height : 10px;

    border-radius : 10px;
    background : $silver;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-radius : 10px;
    background : $silver;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius : 10px;
    background : $gold;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
      <div class='container'>
        <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-12'>
          <ul class='scrollNav'>
            <li><div class='scrollNav-item' role='button' data-si='si-1'>Item one</div></li>
            <li><div class='scrollNav-item' role='button' data-si='si-2'>Item one</div></li>
            <li><div class='scrollNav-item' role='button' data-si='si-3'>Item one</div></li>
            <li><div class='scrollNav-item' role='button' data-si='si-4'>Item one</div></li>
            <li><div class='scrollNav-item' role='button' data-si='si-5'>Item one</div></li>
            <li><div class='scrollNav-item' role='button' data-si='si-6'>Item one</div></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
          <div class='col-12' style='overflow: hidden'>
            <div class='horizontalScroll'>
              <div class='horizontalScroll-item'  data-si='si-1'>
                <img src='//placeimg.com/300/350/nature/grayscale' loading='lazy'>
              </div>

              <div class='horizontalScroll-item' data-si='si-2'>
                <img src='//placeimg.com/300/350/nature' loading='lazy'>
              </div>

              <div class='horizontalScroll-item' data-si='si-3'>
                <img src="//placeimg.com/300/350/arch" loading='lazy'>
              </div>

              <div class='horizontalScroll-item' data-si='si-4'>
                <img src='//placeimg.com/300/350/nature' loading='lazy'>
              </div>

              <div class='horizontalScroll-item' data-si='si-5'>
                <img src="//placeimg.com/300/350/arch" loading='lazy'>          
              </div>                                 

              <div class='horizontalScroll-item' data-si='si-6'>
                <img src='//placeimg.com/300/350/nature/grayscale' loading='lazy'>
              </div>

              <div class='horizontalScroll-item' data-si='si-7'>
                <img src='//placeimg.com/300/350/nature' loading='lazy'>
              </div>

              <div class='horizontalScroll-item' data-si='si-8'>
                <img src="//placeimg.com/300/350/arch" loading='lazy'>
              </div>

              <div class='horizontalScroll-item' data-si='si-9'>
                <img src='//placeimg.com/300/350/nature' loading='lazy'>
              </div>

              <div class='horizontalScroll-item' data-si='si-10'>
                <img src="//placeimg.com/300/350/arch" loading='lazy'>          
              </div>  


            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: What have you tested so far? Have you googled for "js scroll horizontally"?

Comment: I have, but I think the challenge is moving the elements i'm leaning towards using slickjs and taking to the design team about dropping the scroll bar and adding some arrows. That plugin has a GoTo function that may solve this.

Comment: Sounds from your description that slickjs(or other image carousel) will be a good fit. It comes with buttons that can be moved around quite easy if needed. Maybe use the slider syncing that slick has instead of a scrollbar?

Comment: I've use it quite often, but never like this.